# How do I assign a value from database to a scal html radio button?

Tags: html, scala, radio-button, default-value

I am trying to assign to a radio button the default value read from the database through a ScaLa parameter, I cannot use an IF loop inside the tag. Any idea?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="emailConsent" id="emailConsent" class="checkbox" @if(sessionData.user.receiveNews = true ) {checked}>
```

I have the error "reassignment to val" when I try to compile

Comment: What is this supposed to be? Twirl template?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to assign the value `true` to `sessionData.user.receiveNews`, which might explain the error. I think you wanted `@if(sessionData.user.receiveNews == true)` (note double equals), or—better still—`@if(sessionData.user.receiveNews)`.

Comment: Thank you @MikeAllen, now it compiles but still it doesn't check the right option...